# SASS/TFS best practice

Tags: asp.net, tfs, sass, compass-sass

I got my workplace to agree to using SASS/Compass and we work in ASP.NET MVC3 with a TFS server. My concern is when the 3 of us front end developers are working on the same site at the same time writing SASS it's going to cause issues.

Does anyone else have workflow experience using SASS and TFS? What kind of issues did you run into? How did you solve them? Suggestions would be very appreciated

Comment: It shouldn't be any different then CSS. Are you on git?

Comment: No. We use TFS(Team Foundation Server) for source controling.

Comment: why would it cause any issues?

Comment: @Betty I see it causing issues because currently only one person is allowed to check out files at a time. If we are all compiling to 1 stylesheet only one person can work at a time. I was curious if other people have good workflows for teams with more than one person writing CSS on the same project

Comment: Sounds like your issue lays with exclusive checkouts being turned on, this will cause more headaches than just when people are editing sass/css.  Are you generating the css on the fly at the server, or checking it into source control too?

Comment: @Betty Is there a way to generate it on the server? Currently we check it into source control because my team doesn't have any control over the promote process

Comment: There's a nuget package for sass which extends the new bundling optimisation stuff from Microsoft. http://nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss/1.6.9  It's designed for use with MVC4 but works with 3, and probably webforms too.

Comment: @Betty thanks I'll look into that because we are using MVC4 for the projects that are going to contain SASS

Comment: @Betty I tried the extension it seems to work well. I just can't figure out how to make it minify the .css file it generates?

Comment: There appears to be a property UseNativeMinification on SassAndScssSettings which is created from the webconfig bundleTransformer/sassAndScss

Comment: @Betty got it, thanks :) Could you post this as an answer so I can give you rep you deserve for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not checking the resulting css file into source control, but to use the bundling feature in mvc4 along with a [sass nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss/1.6.9) to generate the css file on the server. That way you don't need to deal with merging the css file when you get latest or check in, it also gets around some of the headaches you'll get with exclusive checkouts turned on.

Also make sure you enable the minification setting, there appears to be a property UseNativeMinification on SassAndScssSettings which is created from the webconfig bundleTransformer/sassAndScss